# I have tried to creat a piece of code to detect browser resolution

Tags: php, html

Hey guys and gals I have created this PHP code to detect a browser very new to coding and am a beginner but is not working anyone seems to know why I have thoroughly tried to fix this anything is helpful many thanks.

<

```
html>
<script>
document.cookie="height="+screen.height;// this function allows you to display the cookies to the user, it would display the screen height to the user 
document.cookie="width="+scenter code herereen.width;// this does the same, it allows you to display the cookies to the user which would display the width of the screen
window.location="resolution.php"
</script>
</html>

<?php
echo "<p>The screen height is ".$_COOKIE['height']." pixels</p>";// this will display the height of the screen that you are using in pixels 
echo "<p>The screen width is ".$_COOKIE['width']." pixels</p>";// this will display the width of the screen that you are using 
?>
```

Comment: Cookies are sent by the client with a request. They won’t be available for processing by PHP until you make another request.

Comment: Page life cycle.... PHP runs fully. Page is loaded in browser, JavaScript runs. They do NOT run together

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying won't work, because **PHP is executed on the server side**, JavaScript on the client side.

PHP is executed on the server when the user requests the page.

Then, all is sended to the user and the browser executes the JavaScript.

To achieve your goal, I would recommend you making an AJAX call to your PHP Script after JavaScript detected the browser size.

### Example:

```
<script>
var height = screen.height; 
var width = screen.width;
$.ajax({
   url: 'resolution.php?height=' + height + '&width=' + width
}); 
</script>
```

Now in your resolution.php:

```
<?php
$height = $_GET['height'];
$width = $_GET['width'];
```

Please note, my example requires jQuery for the AJAX part.